# Adding Columns in loop pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a 2 dataframes each with 2 columns (named the same in both df's) and I want to add them together to make a third column.

```
df1['C']=df1[['A','B']].sum(axis=1) 
 df1['D']=df1[['E','G']].sum(axis=1)
df2['C']=df2[['A','B']].sum(axis=1) 
 df2['D']=df2[['E','G']].sum(axis=1)
```

However in reality its more complicated than this. So can I put these in a dictionary and loop?

I'm still figuring out how to structure dictionarys for this type of problem, so any advice would be great.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
all_dfs=[df1,df2]

for df in all_dfs:

dict={Out=['C'], in=['A','B]
    Out2=['D'], in2=['E','G]
}

for i in dict:
    df[i]=df[['i[1....
```

I'm a bit lost in how to build this last bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change dictionary name because `dict` is python code word, then change it by key with output column and value by list of input columns and last loop by `items()` method:

```
d= {'C':['A','B'],'D': ['E','G']}

for k, v in d.items():
    #checking key and value of dict
    print (k)
    print (v) 
    df[k]=df[v].sum(axis=1)
```

EDIT:

Here is simplier working with dictionary of DataFrames, use `sum` and last create anoter dictionary of DataFrames:

```
all_dfs= {'first': df1, 'second':df2}
out = {}

for name, df in all_dfs.items():
    d= {'C':['A','B'],'D': ['E','G']}
    for k, v in d.items():
        df[k]=df[v].sum(axis=1)
        #fill empty dict by name
        out[name] = df

print (out)
print (out['first'])
print (out['second'])
```

Comment: This works great. I've just had another idea, can I do this to 2 dataframes as well?

Comment: you gave me this yesterday: all_df=[Price,RSP]

Price, RSP = [d.reindex(forindex) for d in all_df]

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to apply this in this situation

Comment: So need dictionary of DataFrames in output?

Comment: I think so, basically I have it currently like this:

Comment: d= {'C':['A','B'],'D': ['E','G']}

for k, v in d.items():

    df[k]=df[v].sum(axis=1)    df[2k]=df2[v].sum(axis=1)

Comment: @fred.schwartz - hmmm, so output are 2 DataFrames, one with `C` column sand second with `D` column?

Comment: I'm not explaing this very well. I'll edit the question

Comment: @fred.schwartz - hmmm, more complicated, give me some time.

Comment: @fred.schwartz - Added solution, please check it.