# After applying comparison operator how to output to another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some trading data in my `dataframe`. What I am trying to do is to check if value in one column is larger than in another based on a couple of conditions. After that I want to create a new column and output the result (-1,1 or 0).

```
for n in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['Close'].iloc[n] > df['Ichi'].iloc[n] and df['Close'].iloc[n-1] < df['Ichi'].iloc[n]:
        print("1")
    elif df['Close'].iloc[n]< df['Ichi'].iloc[n] and df['Close'].iloc[n-1] > df['Ichi'].iloc[n]:
       print("-1")
    else:
       print("0")
```

The conditions are: if current ['Close'] value is larger than current ['Ichi'] value and ['Close'] previous value was less than current ['Ichi'] then output 1. Otherwise 0. And the opposite thing should output -1. I understand how to print but could not make it output to separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas is better avoid loops, because slow, if exist vectorized solution, here with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
m1 = df['Close'] > df['Ichi']
m2 = df['Close'].shift() < df['Ichi']
m3 = df['Close'] < df['Ichi']
m4 = df['Close'].shift() > df['Ichi']

df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m3 & m4], [1,-1], 0)
```

Comment: It worked! Many thanks! What if eventually I will have multiple dataframes and calculate same thing for them with the purpose of making a visualized table where I can effectively track where I have these signals (0,1,-1). I am getting this dataframe using API of crypto exchange. If I pull out 20 df will I need to place them all in 1 dataframe and then create vectors? I am trying to understand the logic how to move forward

Comment: @kirillzakharov - It depends what need, one solution is join all DataFrame together by `concat` like `dfs = [df1, df2, df3, .., df20]` and `df_big = pd.concat(dfs)` and then working with only one DataFrame. Another is loop by  dictionary of DataFrames like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896894/2901002) and process each Dataframe separately.